# Simpel way to get Google Analytics 4 (GA4) data with PHP

Tags: analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to get the most simple PHP script to retreive GA4 data. It's for internal use so want to use an api key only to keep it simple (no Oauth).

This is what I have:

```php
       
$apiKey = 'MY API KEY';
$propertyId = 'properties/123456789';

//Make the API call
$url = "https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta:runReport?key={$apiKey}";
```

And using POST to this URL. But when i check the URL directly i get an 404. Also script isn't returning anything.

(Edit: Did a shorter version, because the complete script couldn't get posted here it seems)